# Pipeline is skipping task when it shouldn't?

Tags: openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have an Openshift/Tekton pipeline. I have a task that outputs a true/false `passed` result if certain tests pass:

```yaml
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: test-repo
spec:
  results:
    - name: passed
      type: string
  steps:
    - image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest'
      name: repo-passed
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env pwsh
        if (Run-Tests){
          Set-Content -Path $(results.passed.path) -Value $true -Force
        }
```

I have a second task that is supposed to run if the above task returns 'True', and a third task that outputs the `passed` result for debugging purposes:

```yaml
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: my-pipeline
spec:
  tasks:
    - name: test-repo-task
      taskRef:
        kind: Task
        name: test-repo
    - name: do-stuff
      runAfter:
        - test-repo-task
      taskRef:
        kind: Task
        name: other-task
      when:
        - input: 'True'
          operator: in
          values:
            - $(tasks.test-repo.results.passed)
    - name: show-task-result
      params:
        - name: PS_COMMANDS
          value: echo "$(tasks.test-repo-docs.results.passed)"
        - name: PATH_CONTEXT
          value: .
        - name: POWERSHELL_IMAGE
          value: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
      runAfter:
        - do-stuff
      taskRef:
        kind: ClusterTask
        name: powershell
```

The `show-task-result` outputs `True`, but the `do-stuff` task is still skipping every time. I've tried changing the `when` condition to all lower case ('true'), I've also tried changing the value I output in the PowerShell script from a boolean (`$true`) to string ('`true`') but there was no difference.

I also tried swapping the `when` condition input/values:

```yaml
when:
  - input: $(tasks.test-repo.results.passed)
    operator: in
    values:
      - 'true'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this note](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#using-results:%7E:text=Note%20that%20when%20expressions%20are%20whitespace%2Dsensitive) from the documentation, my result output was appending a newline, causing the `when` test to fail.

To fix this I used the [`-NoNewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content#-nonewline) parameter of `Set-Content` (akin to the [`tr`](https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html) example in the docs: `tr -d \n`):

```yaml
steps:
  - image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest'
    name: repo-passed
    script: |
      #!/usr/bin/env pwsh
      if (Run-Tests){
        Set-Content -Path $(results.passed.path) -Value $true -Force -NoNewLine
      }
```